# Azure DevOps Build Process Create Git Branch

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, git-branch

folks,

I'll give you a brief description of my problem. I have an Angular App in a TFS Git repository, now I want to build this app with Azure DevOps, when that's done, I want to create a new Git Branch from Master

The build process runs smoothly, only creating a new branch is not possible. Can you help me ?

I try it with a Powershell Script  like

> git branch [aNewBranch] master

or

> git checkout -q [aNewBranch]

but it don't work.

Comment: What is your output? do you have errors? try `git checkout -b [newBranch]`

Comment: 2018-12-20T07:53:09.3854711Z ##[error]Switched to a new branch 'Release_'

Comment: Please share the full log..

Comment: 2018-12-20T07:53:08.5838175Z ##[section]Starting: Neuen Release Branch im Repository anlegen 
2018-12-20T07:53:08.5843371Z ==============================================================================
2018-12-20T07:53:08.5843531Z Task         : PowerShell
2018-12-20T07:53:08.5843658Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script
2018-12-20T07:53:08.5843758Z Version      : 1.2.3
2018-12-20T07:53:08.5843856Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-12-20T07:53:08.5843971Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613736)

Comment: 2018-12-20T07:53:08.5844119Z ==============================================================================
2018-12-20T07:53:08.5948460Z ##[command]. 'C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\2b803675-38f7-4f3c-81ff-d6e2f6e81bbc.ps1' 
2018-12-20T07:53:09.3854711Z ##[error]Switched to a new branch 'Release_'

Comment: 2018-12-20T07:53:09.3867144Z M package-lock.json
2018-12-20T07:53:09.3867281Z M package.json
2018-12-20T07:53:09.5111122Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 0 and had 1 error(s) written to the error stream.
2018-12-20T07:53:09.5125732Z ##[section]Finishing: Neuen Release Branch im Repository anlegen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you need a branch from your master branch [with all changes as iin master branch].

Do these steps.

```
Just check the logs 
    git log --oneline -10

Fetch everything from repo
    git fetch origin [or any remote name]

Keep checking the logs 
    git log --oneline -10

go to master branch 
    git checkout master
        if master branch does not exists in your local machine - 
            create it with : git checkout -b master 

Now you are in master branch. 

rebase with master branch 
    git rebase origin/master

If you have some code changes already done in master branch (I am guessing the changes are not committed) - 
        git commit -am "Commit message here.. for your changes" [params : a for all, m for message]

Keep checking the logs 
    git log --oneline -10

Currently you are in master with new changes [with new commit]

Now go to new branch with changes [as it is in master - I guess this is what you expect]
        git checkout -b NewBranch

Keep checking the logs 
    git log --oneline -10
```

Comment: @MartinZyk , Let me know if you are expecting anything more

Comment: Maybe I think wrong, but I already checked out the current branch? why check it out again? azure DevOps does the first step to get the sources.

Comment: 2018-12-20T07:49:40.2305401Z ##[command]git config --get remote.origin.url
2018-12-20T07:49:40.2708350Z ##[command]git config gc.auto 0
2018-12-20T07:49:40.3100460Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.http://xxxxxx/tfs/xxxxxxx/WebApps/_git/workflow-admin.extraheader
2018-12-20T07:49:40.3450035Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
2018-12-20T07:49:40.3891169Z ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin

Comment: 2018-12-20T07:49:40.5556690Z ##[command]git checkout --progress --force 4d80f56edb110f2efcc9b8dddea0db2e03477890

Comment: i will tell you - You have a repository in server. You have cloned it. using power shell you went inside that directory. After that what happened ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185541/discussion-between-martinzyk-and-smilyface).